# Google Map closes automatically after moving certain distance

Tags: android, google-maps, android-location, fusedlocationproviderapi

Hi I am developing an distance calculator app with Google maps. When the user opens the map,it will display the user current position with blue dot.

When the user moves, it fetches the latlong and send to server through webservice. I have tested the applicaiton in following devices and got this issue

1. in lyf mobile(1GB ram) the closes automatically when the user moves
   upto 5 kms.
2. In redmi(3GB ram),the map closes after user reach 10 km.

> I added both large heap and multidex true.But the same error is
>   handling. i am using fused location service api.

I am new to android, any help would be very valuable.

Comment: post error log here

Comment: @divyesh..i cnt get the log..bcoz i am getting error only when i am moving..that time i dont know how to get log...any way for that?

Comment: alogcat app in playstore

Comment: @lucky use http://fabric.io/ or firebase.google.com for crash reports

Comment: i installed firebase by following some tutorials ..but its not working

Comment: can aynbody know ,how to use alogcat app to see log?